# Multivariate R apply function

Tags: r

I'd like to calculate weighted quantiles (reldist::wtd.quantile) over certain array margins using apply() but the function requires covariate weights for each observation.

Is there a version of apply that would operate something like this:

```
myfunc <- function(var1, var2) wtd.quantile(x = var1, weight = var2)

out <- apply(array1, array2, MARGIN=c(3,5,6), myfunc)
```

where the apply function knows to send array1 data as var1 and array2 data as var2?

I'm about to make this function myself by vectorizing array1 and array2 and using purrr::map2 but wanted to check if a more efficient function already exists.

Cheers!

Comment: please share your data

Comment: Do you have an array with 6 dimensions?? ie i see 6 in the margin

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

If these are two arrays, one option is to loop over the third array margin, get the corresponding elements in a `list` and apply the function

```
lapply(seq_len(dim(array1)[3]), function(i) myfunc(array1[3, 5, i], array2[3, 5, i]))
```